# Would vegetation-like decorations help to alleviate homesickness on a Lunar or Mars colony?

Tags: culture, planets, habitability

The sterile and unchanging landscape of the Martian global desert could become tiresome for any Martian colonialist. Terraforming has been proposed but seems undoable for a long time to come.

So what about installing plastic stuff around a Martian colony which looks like trees and grass waving in an imaginary wind? And with some mechanical birds and hares and squirrels around (or whatever your climate zone is like in springtime). To make us feel at home. Although we aren't.

Comment: The edit to my post is completely against the meaning of the question! I don't refer to any "flora", but to dead mechanical simulations of a forest or savannah.

Comment: Flora = plant life. Do forests and savannahs not have plant life?

Comment: @Frostfyre I understand your instinct, but I don't refer to flora or life. But to stuff like a plastic christmas tree. It is not alive. It is not flora. But it looks like it. It somehow comforts us when on Mars, maybe. I'm the one asking.

Comment: In other words, artificial flora? Or what am I missing? If it's artificial, it's not alive. (I can see how the 'and fauna' might be considered to change the meaning, but not how the 'artificial flora' bit does.)

Comment: @LindaJeanne If you want to call a plastic Xmas tree "a flora", then okay. But I want to make the point here of the difference between what is actually alive, a flora, and what just looks like it. A plastic pretend-to-be forest. I thank you for our input, because it reveals that my crazy idea here could be better explained. I'll think about it.

Comment: @LocalFluff, well, it's clearly not '_natural_ flora' :).  '_artificial_ flora' seems to me to describe "fake trees and plants" perfectly. (pedantic nit-pick: 'flora' is actually plural, so you wouldn't have 'a flora', just 'flora'. /pedant)

Comment: "Artificial fauna" = "mechanical birds and hares and squirrels". No probs rejecting my edit :) But the terms I used *were* correct. Would "artificial plants and animals" have been better? Not offended or anything, just trying to understand where I went wrong...

Comment: @LindaJeanne Like the artificial flowers allowed in hospitals. Plastics, textiles I don't know how they do it but they fool me. And I've heard that they are given artificial non-allergic flavors too nowadays. Pretend-to-terraforming maybe is cheaper it is anyway only about fooling ourselves to believe that we are at home, right?

Comment: @LocalFluff: Yup, I think it's a really interesting question, which is why I clicked on the link. I think there's a high chance that even artificial flora, as long as it was a reasonably good, would likely have a positive effect. Not an answer, since I don't have anything handy to back it up with)

Comment: @MarvMills Can be that I don't understand the meaning of "artificial flora". I spontaneously understand it as something living created by human science (which hasn't happened yet). But I'm completely new to this community and its language. I'm a bit of an elephant in a Porcelain Boutique here.

Comment: @LocalFluff: that would generally be "artificial _life_", since you are artificially creating something alive. I believe that artificial _flora/fauna_ is generally understood to mean not alive, fake. :)

Comment: @LindaJeanne No, it is not alive, it's not "flora". I don't suggest engineering life, that is hugely hard and wouldn't survive on the Moon or on Mars anyway. I suggest dumb plastic decorations.

Comment: @LocalFluff -- sorry, I was unclear. I was saying that IF you had meant artificial living things, _then_ that _would have_ been "artificial life". But since you are talking about *FAKE* plants that are *NOT alive*, that's "artificial flora" or "artificial plants". Hopefully I'm making more sense now?

Comment: You don't need an imaginary wind, as sufficient breeze already exists.  Combine that with the melting of ice (terraforming), and you will have more than enough wind to keep those artificial leaves blowing.   Like on earth, the soil itself could be reshaped into fantastic objects.  I wonder how fast a CPU would be if the silicon was formed using martian soil, instead of earths......   hmmm...

Comment: @SanuelJackson You'd hardly notice a [hurricane on Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/could-you-feel-the-wind-on-mars) because the air is near vacuum. There are dust storms only because the dust particles are as small as cigarette smoke particles.

Comment: This is not opinion based.  there are plenty of psychological studies about familiar objects and mental well being.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** but...

The problem would likely be the cost of shipping. Raw oil is very unlikely to be found on Mars to make the plastic with, so your down to synthetic and high energy processes to manufacture them locally, or shipping them in.

It would likely be more helpful to a colony to have actual plants around, this would have the added bonus of filtering air as well. Though they would require water. These plants could be shipped to Mars as seeds to cut down on the weight requirement. Locally generated compost could be used for soil and presumably the colony will have some source of water or they are going to have trouble lasting very long.

From the physiological point of view plants have been shown to have a therapeutic effect on astronauts. Don Pettit famously kept the blog of the astro zucchini while he was in orbit ( http://www.fragileoasis.org/blog/2012/4/astrog-in-zerog-the-diary-of-a-space-zucchini-part-1/ )

I can see this idea helping, however there would have to be a significant advantage over say some clever 3D effect screens acting as windows to make it worth the extra cost. As they say in space travel every gram is expensive.

Comment: Yeah, carbon is rare inside of the "frost line" for carbon volatiles. No problem on Titan though. But at Mars there's a co2 atmosphere which if combined with light hydrogen imported or extracted from water, could be turned into plastics. Anyway, I and most people spend more and more time watching a pixelated screen anyway. Less and less need for doing anything physical.

Comment: Most fruit bearing plants and vegetables, consume more oxygen than co2, so while providing food from their flowers, ferns would likely be a better choice.

Comment: @SanuelJackson But terraforming Mars is thousands of years off. The crazy thought here is to dress the surrounding of a potential Mars colony with something that looks like something humans can relate to, as a contrast to that totally eventless frozen Martian landscape. To help cure their boredom. The spring came late where I live, it is a fantastic event every year, the sky gets blue and white and the ground gets green, sea birds wake me up at 5 o'clock with their mad screams. Taking all of that away won't kill astronauts, but it would change their moods in the long run.

Comment: @LocalFluff I agree, sort of. I've edited to make it a bit clearer.